# Microsoft Teams: Understanding web app & bot samples

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am new in Teams & Bot world, and I have some basic doubts, after reading in the docu and testing its samples.

I have 2 projects running in my Visual Studio:

1. Echo Bot from Bot Framefork
2. HelloWorld app from Teams Samples (with an 'EchoBot' inside)

I can see that Activities from Teams are managed in a different way:

1. ActivityHandler with OnMessageActivityAsync, where each message is received:
   protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext turnContext...
2. ApiController with Post method:
   Task Post([FromBody] Activity activity)

but 1 manages Microsoft.Bot.Schema.IActivity

and 2 manages Microsoft.Bot.Connector.IActivity

Maybe it sounds basic, but where can I find a simple explanation about these 2 different ways to manage incoming messages and creating responses/updates,...?

My goal is to have an application with Message Extension (like in 2), to get commands from TEAMS (with @MyApp...), but I need to send activities like Cards (like in 1).

I need to reply (Reply1) an incoming message from a user (Message1), and when I finish a local task, add another reply to the same message (Reply2 to Message1). Both are not new messages, but sent in the same "thread"

With these requirements, what is my best start point?

Thanks a lot,

Diego

Comment: The two methods you see are the two different versions of the SDK. Please go through the basics of [Bot Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations) to understand creating and sending responses. Message Extension cards are usually used to query some information and send it to a user in form of a card. If you want to send the card to the bot itself and send a reply to the card, that needs to be handled in the bot code itself. Please let me know if you need any assistance.

Comment: 2 methods are Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3 and v4, correct?
Connector.Activity is v3 and Schema.Activity is v4. 

I don't want to send a card to the bot, but from the bot. As a response to a request from the user (when a bot option is used '@bot'->popOptionsMenu->select 1). And after a while, the bot will response again, but in the same thread

Should I think about using Scheme version? I am new with that world, maybe it is better to focus only on 1 method...

Comment: For my purpose, I am confused about how to send a command to my bot (in order to do some task and send back a response). I saw Message Extensions (1), but also Bot menu options (2)... I only see (1) in v3 (IsComposeExtensionQuery() method with received Activity). But I can not find how a command (2) is processed in the bot

Comment: Let's get the terminology clear first. Are you trying to create a bot or a Message Extension? Maybe share some screenshots for better understanding?

Comment: I'm afraid I have problems to understand clearly all the concepts... I need to receive in my code a command (1) from a user in a TEAMS channel. Then I will do a task and response to that message (in the channel) or to the user (private chat), depending on my task result. This command (1) will appear in a popup menu ('What can I do') when @MYNAME is entered by a user in the channel. I understood this is a Message Extension, but I saw Bot Menu with commands...

Comment: When you type @BotName and You see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g39Ik.png), these are message extension commands which can be used to query some information and send them in form of a card to the users [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtM9n.png) is how it looks, but when you type atBotName and you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqtXX.png), these are the [bot commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-menus). When you click any of these bot commands, your bot will receive this message and reply accordingly.

Comment: Please notice the difference in the images. Please let me know if you still have an issue.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks a lot. Maybe bot commands are what I need, and I can forget Message Extensions at this moment. I see 'Title' and 'Description' for each command (no id), so they are processed my name in the bot, correct?
About previous versions issue I wrote about, what I understand is: 'Ms.Teams.Samples.HelloWorld' is v3 (ApiController & Post method) and Csharp_doNetCore' samples are v4 (ActivityHandler with OnMessageActivityAsync,...). Correct?
So I think I should use v4 samples at start point.

Comment: Correct!! You need to work on bot commands and yes commands do not have an id so you need to process the request based on the Text you receive. Also, you are right about the v3 and v4 samples.

Comment: Ok!! And would it be possible to have a menu with these two commands? 1. Just a command (text received in the bot), 2. Command which requires a string parameter entered by the user

Comment: Bot commands are just the text the user will send to the bot. Just an easy way of clicking and sending the text instead of typing it.  I am not sure what do u mean by " Command which requires a string parameter entered by the user"

Comment: For example, option 1 is 'Close' (to close an app) and option 2 is 'Call a number', which requires the number to call. Maybe for that I could not use bot commands

Comment: You can add any text you want to send to your bot, into the bot commands.

Comment: Ok, I understand, the user selects the command from the list and then adds the number after the command... Sorry, I see now